# Is it possible for me to achieve the equivalent of "display: none" but have the element still in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

My situation is the following.

Today I decided that I wanted to make my site more mobile-friendly. My site uses `table`s in several places. Because those are difficult to fit onto a mobile device if they have more than a couple columns, I decided to hit a couple columns with `display: none;` inside a media query. However, that screwed up my Javascript that extracts information from those columns. So, is there a way to make elements take up no space but still be in the DOM for when I use JQuery selectors on them? I realize there's some code smell going on, but it was a late decision to mobilize these tables.

Comment: `display:none` doesn't remove the element from the DOM nor does it prevent selection using jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, +1 to what Denys has to say. You must be selecting the objects in an odd way. Can you post the code you use to read through the table contents?

Comment: Are your selectors containing `:visible`?

Comment: EDIT: I'm going to post some code because I still can't figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can achieve this in simple way.

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/vzdwLmd0/

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // if you aldy known specific column to extract data
    alert($('table td').eq(2).text());

    // if you have some class to extract data from the column
    alert($('td.hidden_val').text());
});
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td style="display:none;">3</td>
        <td class="hidden_val" style="display:none;">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```